# EXTJS 6.5: External properties file with variables to use in Index.html

Tags: extjs

I have an EXTJS6.5 application. I want to use variables in my index.html that come from a properties file. However the change of the values of these variables should not require a new build of the application.  This means that the variable can be changed if required (Without the need to build the extjs code).

Can someone please help with this?

I have already gone thru other threads where index.html can have placeholders, but do not seem to have a concrete example.

This is my properties file (Runtime.js)

```
{
    "appUrl": "http://myappurl.com",
    "appId": "10"
}

Then I want to use these variables in my index.html as such:
```

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name="description" content="MyApp">

    <title>MyApp</title>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="myicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/dist/myapp-resources.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myapp-app-loading">
        <div class="myapp-spinner"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Ext = Ext || {};
        Ext.beforeLoad = function (tags) {
            Ext.manifest = 'classic'; // this name must match a build profile name
        };
    </script>

    <script src="Runtime.js"></script>

    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Cmd to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" data-app="6d7f3123-ffca-44d3-8ed2-14fr2w6be804" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="{{Runtime.appUrl}}/configuration/MyConstants.js"></script>
    <script src="{{Runtime.appUrl}}/resources/mycharts/mycharts.js"></script>
    <script src="{{Runtime.appUrl}}/resources/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Will this work this way? Or pls suggest any better way to do this..thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `Runtime.js` file has a syntax error. Is not valid javascript file.

`Runtime.js` should be:

```
window.appUrl="http://myappurl.com";
window.appId="10";
```

And you can use these variables like `window.appUrl`/`window.appid` in script block, not in html block.

You can do workaround to resolve the problem: You can generate includes from `Runtime.js`.
Example:

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name="description" content="MyApp">

    <title>MyApp</title>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="myicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/dist/myapp-resources.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myapp-app-loading">
        <div class="myapp-spinner"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Ext = Ext || {};
        Ext.beforeLoad = function (tags) {
            Ext.manifest = 'classic'; // this name must match a build profile name
        };
    </script>

    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Cmd to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" data-app="6d7f3123-ffca-44d3-8ed2-14fr2w6be804" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Runtime.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

`Runtime.js`

```
window.appUrl="http://myappurl.com";
window.appId="10";

var script = document.createElement("script")
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = window.appUrl+"/configuration/MyConstants.js";

var script2 = document.createElement("script")
script2.type = "text/javascript";
script2.src = window.appUrl+"/resources/mycharts/mycharts.js";

var script3 = document.createElement("script")
script3.type = "text/javascript";
script3.src = window.appUrl+"/resources/ckeditor/ckeditor.js";

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[document.getElementsByTagName("body").length-1].appendChild(script);
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[document.getElementsByTagName("body").length-1].appendChild(script2);
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[document.getElementsByTagName("body").length-1].appendChild(script3);
```

Updated 2019-07-17:

If you want to require script before application launches you must add reference to script in `app.json` in `js` block (Which can't be done because you want to personalize the source of scripts).

Second option is change in `app.js` you can do `Ext.Loader.loadScript` like:

```
Ext.Loader.loadScript({
    url: 'my.js',
    onLoad: function(){
        Ext.application({
            name: 'Fiddle',
            extend: 'Fiddle.Application',
            autoCreateViewPort: false
        });
    },
    onError: function(){
        console.log('error');
    }
});`
```

Comment: However I have another issue.When my I build my application via sencha cmd, get error for Highchart and CKEditor. Seems like the resources are loaded after the Application.js launches. 

Is there a way to ensure that all are loaded before the application launches?

The error that I get is as follows:

`highcharts-3d.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: ** Highcharts is not defined **
    at highcharts-3d.js:8
    at highcharts-3d.js:8`

Any help with this issue? Thanks

Comment: You should use `app.json` instead of `index.html` to set position of files loading or you need to use template ex. `jinja`.

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you mean. Can you help with an example please?

Comment: Check my edited answer, you need to do templating like jinja or do `Ext.Loader.loadScripts` before launch the application

Comment: Hello,

I tried like this:

`
Ext.Loader.loadScript({
    url: 'resources/highcharts/highcharts.js',
    onLoad: function(){
        console.log('highcharts loaded');
    },
    onError: function(){
        console.log('error');
    }
});

`

I get the loaded consoles. But my highchart does not show in my app. Anything I am missing here?

Comment: This is a great answer! Finally someone who knows how to answer a question! Thank you!